# How to get the formula value before inserting the records

Tags: apex, trigger, formula

I have a custom formula field on Contact which refers Account field.
I want to get the value of that formula field before doing any insert operation, how can I do this?

I tried using recalculateFormulas() method but its always returning null.

Here is the code which I tried.

```
Contact conObj = new Contact();
conObj.LastName='Last';
conObj.AccountId = '001f100001NKm4t';
conObj.recalculateFormulas();
system.debug('>>> conObj... '+conObj.Account_Completed__c);
```

Comment: is it cross object formula? recalulate formyla doesnt work on cross object formulas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> recalculateFormulas() method doesn’t recalculate cross-object
>   formulas. If you call this method on objects that have both
>   cross-object and non-cross-object formula fields, only the
>   non-cross-object formula fields are recalculated.
>
> Each recalculateFormulas call counts against the SOQL query limits.
>   See Execution Governors and Limits.

As recalculateFormulas already consumes a SOQL, why not do a dummy dml and requery the cross object fields.

You can do a dummy insert to see cross object referenced values via SOQL and then rollthem back if not needed.

```
public static Contact dummyInsertContact(Contact con){
    Savepoint sp = Database.setSavepoint();
    upsert con;

    Contact newCOn = [Select id,Name, Account_Completed__c from Contact where Id =:con.Id];

    Database.rollback(sp);
    con.Id=null;
   return newCOn;
```

}

And then your main code will be

```
Contact conObj = new Contact();
conObj.LastName='Last';
conObj.AccountId = '001f100001NKm4t';
Contact dumCOntac = dummyInsertContact(conObj);
system.debug('>>> conObj... '+dumCOntac.Account_Completed__c);
```

Comment: It seems even not working for normal formula fields like: CASE( 
MOD(TODAY() - DATE(1900, 1, 7), 7), 
0, 'Sunday', 
1,'Monday', 
2,'Tuesday', 
3, 'Wednesday', 
4, 'Thursday', 
5, 'Friday', 
'Saturday' 
)